# Can the RecyclerView scroll with the rest of the fragment layouts?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have set up a `RecyclerView` adapter with `ViewPager` in an activity namely `TvShowEpisodeDetails` , it works well but there is one issue, the Layout of RecyclerView is fixed while scrolling up and down in the Fragment(TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment). But I want it to scroll with them.

The `RecyclerView` and `ViewPager` are both set inside `viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay.xml` Layout , and both has been settup in The Activity.

`TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment` is the fragment class which belongs to activity class `TvShowEpisodeDetails` , the fragment creates as many episodes as a TV Show season can offer.

[image]

And off course this issue will be gone if I set `RecyclerView` adapter inside fragment, but I will get non-fixable highlighting and scrolling issues , that is why I set it inside the activity because it does not give those issues.

I need to make it work somehow inside the activity.

**My goal is that `RecyclerView` and `ViewPager` has to be in the same layout `XML` file and they both must either be in the activity or fragment class**

**Is it possible to make the `RecyclerView` scroll with rest of the fragment layouts?**

**or**

**Is it possible to do it programmatically?**

**Here is the activity**

```
public class TvShowEpisodeDetails extends MizActivity{

    
    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBus = MizuuApplication.getBus();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set theme
        setTheme(R.style.Mizuu_Theme_NoBackground);

       


        // setting episodeslist
        final ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(TvShowEpisode e : mEpisodes){
            episodeslist.add(new PlanetModel(e.mEpisode));
        }


        // setting RecyclerView
        mEpisodesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.episodesLIST);


        // Setting LinearLayoutManager
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //mEpisodesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mEpisodesList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        // Setting RecyclerView Adapter
        PlanetAdapter.OnItemClickListener indicatorCallback = new PlanetAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String item) {
                SharedPreferences getPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int pos = getPref.getInt("newPosition", 0);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos,false);
            }
        };
        final PlanetAdapter planetAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(episodeslist,indicatorCallback);
        mEpisodesList.setAdapter(planetAdapter);


        // Setting ViewPager
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                planetAdapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
                planetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mEpisodesList.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
                //mEpisodesList.scrollToPosition(position);
                for (int i=0; i<episodeslist.size(); i++)
                {
                    episodeslist.get(i).setPlanetSelected(false);
                }
                episodeslist.get(position).setPlanetSelected(true);
                ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(TvShowEpisodeDetails.this, mToolbar, 0, mEpisodes.get(position).getTitle(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mEpisodes.size(); i++) {
                if (mEpisodes.get(i).getSeason().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mSeason)) && mEpisodes.get(i).getEpisode().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mEpisode))) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#068006"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/episodesLIST"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Here is the `XML` layout of the fragment which is inflated in `onCreateView` of the fragment class**

**episode_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard">

    <com.miz.views.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/observableScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/episodePhoto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/backdrop_portrait_height"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg" />

                <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/episodePhoto"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_details_fab_negative_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_36dp"
                    app:fab_colorNormal="#666"
                    app:fab_type="mini" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_details_title_margin_top"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_details_very_small_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_subheader"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/details_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#666"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/content_details_large_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/content_details_small_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/content_details_small_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@string/detailsAirDate"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_area_subheader" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textReleaseDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_area_header"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView61"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@string/detailsRating"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_area_subheader" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_area_header"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/content_details_baseline_margin"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_body_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/director"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_movie_white_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/movie_details_padding"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_body_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/writer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit_white_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/movie_details_padding"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_body_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/guest_stars"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_people_white_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/movie_details_padding"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_body_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder_open_white_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/movie_details_padding"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_details_body_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.miz.views.ObservableScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Update**

***Fragment***

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams") public class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment extends Fragment {




    public TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment() {}

    public static TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment newInstance(String showId, int season, int episode) {
        TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment pageFragment = new TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("showId", showId);
        bundle.putInt("season", season);
        bundle.putInt("episode", episode);
        pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mContext = getActivity();

        mBus = MizuuApplication.getBus();

        mShowFileLocation = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getBoolean(SHOW_FILE_LOCATION, true);

        mPicasso = MizuuApplication.getPicassoDetailsView(getActivity());

        mMediumItalic = TypefaceUtils.getRobotoMediumItalic(mContext);
        mMedium = TypefaceUtils.getRobotoMedium(mContext);
        mCondensedRegular = TypefaceUtils.getRobotoCondensedRegular(mContext);

        mDatabaseHelper = MizuuApplication.getTvEpisodeDbAdapter();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocalBroadcastUtils.UPDATE_TV_SHOW_EPISODE_DETAILS_OVERVIEW));

        loadEpisode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            loadEpisode();
            loadData();
        }
    };

    private void loadEpisode() {
        if (!getArguments().getString("showId").isEmpty() && getArguments().getInt("season") >= 0 && getArguments().getInt("episode") >= 0) {
            Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisode(getArguments().getString("showId"), getArguments().getInt("season"), getArguments().getInt("episode"));

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                mEpisode = new TvShowEpisode(getActivity(),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SHOW_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                );

                mEpisode.setFilepaths(MizuuApplication.getTvShowEpisodeMappingsDbAdapter().getFilepathsForEpisode(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SHOW_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE))
                ));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_details, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBackdrop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBackground);
        mEpisodePhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.episodePhoto);
        mDetailsArea = view.findViewById(R.id.details_area);

        mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        mSeasonEpisodeNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        mDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mFileSource = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mAirDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textReleaseDate);
        mRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        mDirector = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.director);
        mWriter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.writer);
        mGuestStars = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.guest_stars);
        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.observableScrollView);
        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewUtils.animateFabJump(v, new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        play();
                    }
                });
            }
        });  
        
        ...

    }
    
    ...

}
```

Comment: not really related to your question, but you seem to be using really old and outdated dependencies, you should consider using androidX dependencies

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I will definitely upgrade , but for now I'm really stuck.

Comment: Your `recyclerview` is not inside the fragment of a `viewPager`. And your scrolling the fragment. If you want your `recyclerView` to scroll with view add it inside the fragment.

Comment: Thanks , You are right and I already did that but I got problem with item highlighting of the recyclerView, so I had no choice but to move it to the activity.

Comment: if I set the recyclerView adapter insdie the fragment then if I click on a recyclerView item a new instance of the fragment will be created over and over again , and I got no solution for it.

Comment: Is it possible to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have set up a `RecyclerView` adapter with `ViewPager` in an activity namely `TvShowEpisodeDetails` , it works well but there is one issue, the Layout of RecyclerView is fixed while scrolling up and down in the Fragment(TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment). But I want it to scroll with them.

It's hard to use the `RecyclerView` outside of the `ViewPager` page fragment; because you can't synchronize and link the touch/motion events when you scroll the page up/down (or when you swipe to next/previous page) between both the page fragment and a standalone (i.e. activity) `RecyclerView`. Even that won't be smooth.

So, the `RecyclerView` should be a part of the `ViewPager` page.

> And off course this issue will be gone if I set RecyclerView adapter inside fragment, but I will get unfixable highlighting and scrolling issues

So, now the issue of adding the `RecyclerView` in the `ViewPager` fragment is the highlighting issue of the `RecyclerView` item when you click on any item or when you swipe the ViewPager to right/left page.

But, the main issue is that there is a `RecyclerView` instance per page, i.e. if you have 5 pages, then you have 5 RecyclerViews.

So, it's a cumbersome to track highlighting only within the `RecyclerView` adapter class. And hence manipulating that with `OnClickListeners` solely will have issues of linking these `RecyclerView` and adapter instances together to update their highlighting item.

So, a simpler approach is to pass a parameter to the `RecyclerView` adapter with the selected item (which is definitely equals to the current ViewPager page position).

And then do a check in the `onBindViewHolder()` if the `position` equals to the passed-in value, then highlight the item; otherwise keep items with the original color.

So, wrapping this up into actions:

- Change the adapter constructor to accept a highlighted_position parameter

```
public PlanetAdapter(ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist, 
                         int highlightedPosition, OnItemClickListener listener)
```

- Whenever you create the ViewPager fragment using `newInstance()` pass-in the current position of the page fragment:

So, in the `TvShowEpisodeDetails` activity:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mEpisodes.size(); i++)
    fragments.add(TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment
                    .newInstance(mShowId, 
                              Integer.parseInt(mEpisodes.get(i).getSeason()),
                              Integer.parseInt(mEpisodes.get(i).getEpisode()), 
                              i)); // The position
```

And in the `TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment` fragment, register this into a field in the fragment argument:

```
public static TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment newInstance(String showId, int season, int episode, int position) { // adding position
    TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment pageFragment = new TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // trimmed code.

    bundle.putInt("position", position); // <<<< into the bundle
    pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return pageFragment;
}
```

- And set that in the adapter creation:

```
int currentPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");
planetAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(episodeslist, currentPosition, new PlanetAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final int pos) {
        mCallback.sendText(pos);
    }
});
```

- And reflect that in the adapter to highlight the item:

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder> {

    private final int highlightedPos;
    public PlanetAdapter(ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist, int highlightedPosition, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.episodeslist = episodeslist;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.highlightedPos = highlightedPosition; // <<<  set the position
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder vh, final int position) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
        PlanetModel planetModel = episodeslist.get(position);
        tv.setText(planetModel.getPlanetName());
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.bg, 0, 0, 0);

        if (highlightedPos == position) { //<<<<< Highlight the item
            vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onClick: Highlight item: " + highlightedPos);

        } else {
            vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onClick: No highlight: " + highlightedPos);
        }
    }
}
```